# htaccess RewriteRule and Redirect 301 don't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

We're trying to set up 301 redirects to make sure Google uses the right category pages. We can't set up a canonical and a normal `Redirect 301 /n.html https://website.com/n.html` doesn't work either, it's just ignored. We're on Opencart 1.5.5.1. The issue is that the 301s are just ignored, they're not implemented at all both Redirect 301 and RewriteRule

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/refrigeration/Multidecks/fresh-meat-multidecks$ https://www.website.co.uk/Multidecks/fresh-meat-multidecks [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/fresh-meat-multidecks$ https://www.website.co.uk/Multidecks/fresh-meat-multidecks/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Remove `/` after `^`

Comment: @anubhava wow is that it? Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Like Anubhava said, the issue is the `/` after the `^`